# index in front of "ip link" or "ip addr" output

Tags: linux

There is an index in front of each network interface in `ip link show` or `ip addr show` output. For example from 1 to 6 here:

```
root@T42:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:41:54:01:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: irda0: <NOARP> mtu 2048 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 8
    link/irda 00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:ce:8b:99:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
root@T42:~#
```

Now if I delete an interface(`ip link del dev tun0`) and create an interface(`ip tuntap add mode tun`), then new index is used:

```
root@T42:~# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:41:54:01:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: irda0: <NOARP> mtu 2048 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 8
    link/irda 00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:13:ce:8b:99:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 500
    link/none 
root@T42:~#
```

What is the purpose of those index numbers? Is there a way to sort based on those index numbers? I mean for example if I create a huge amount of interfaces(for example `for i in {2..5000}; do brctl addbr br"$i"; done`), then those interfaces are not sorted by index number:

```
root@VM-host:~# ip link show | tail
1279: br1246: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether 02:de:92:e5:da:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
1023: br990: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether c2:35:8b:3a:dd:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
767: br734: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether da:e9:52:8f:24:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
511: br478: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether 56:6d:81:a0:71:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
255: br222: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether a6:92:89:f1:ee:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@VM-host:~#
```

Answer (score 3):

The numbers are merely for convenience and are dynamically calculated.

> These numbers are dynamically calculated, so should not be used to refer to the interfaces.

More info you can find [tools-ip-link](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-link.html) and [tools-ip-addr](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html).